# From geeks for geeks Frequencies of Limited Range Array Elements problem

Tags: python, arrays, hash, hashmap, frequency

This is an exercise from gfg must do question. But my code is not passing all the testcases.
Can anyone please help me out here.

```
Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer

Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
37349
27162 38945 3271 34209 37960 17314 13663 17082 37769 2714 19280 17626 34997 33512 29275 25207 4706 12532 34909 23823 272 29688 19312 8154 5091 26858 30814 19105 14105 11303 16863 1861 2961 36601 10157 114 11491 31810 29152 2627 14327 30116 14828 37781 38925 16319 10972 4506 18669 19366 28984 6948 15170 24135 6256 38121 3835 38031 9855 25152 19132 23573 29587 1719 33440 26311 12647 23022 34206 39955 3791 18555 336 7317 12033 7278 27508 5521 24935 15078 915 35478 37253 6863 39182 23429 33867.................

Its Correct output is:
2 4 1 2 5 2 0 4 1 3 1 2 1 3 2 4 4 1 1 0 2 0 4 1 3 5 1 0 1 2 1 3 2 0 1 1 2 0 0 2 1 2 2 1 4 2 0 1 2 2 0 1 2 0 2 4 4 5 2 5 2 1 5 1 2 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 3 1 2 0 3 4 1 2 0 2 3 5 2 2 1 3 1 4 0 3 5 1 1 3 1 2 2 3 2 2 4 1 1 3 1 4 3 4 0 2 1 4 4 2 2 3 3 0 0 0 4 1 2 1 2 4 1 3 1 2 4 0 2 1 1 1 0 3 4 3 2 0 3 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 2 2 3 0 1 2 2 2 0 2 3 2 1 1 3 0 1 5 1 1 1 0 2 0 3 1 2 1 1 1 2 3 3 1 1 3 1 4 1 3 1 1 1 2 2 0 1 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 1 4 1 0 3 1 2 0 3 1 2 1 8 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 4 1 3 0 3 2 1 1 1 1 2 4 2 2 1 4 2 1 3 1 0 .................

And Your Code's output is:
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 2 2 0 0 1 0 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 2 0 1 3 1 0 0 2 1 4 0 1 0 1 0 3 0 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 3 1 0 2 1 0 3 1 3 2 2 0 2 0 2 3 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 3 1 2 0 1 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 2 1 1 1 2 0 1 3 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 2 0 2 1 3 1 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 1 0 3 0 0 1 0 1 0 2 0 2 1 4 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 2 1 0 2 0 0 .................
```

Given an array A[] of n positive integers which can contain integers from 1 to n where elements can be repeated or can be absent from the array. Your task is to count the frequency of all elements from 1 to n.

Input:
n = 5
A[] = {2,3,2,3,5}
Output:
0 2 2 0 1
Explanation:
Counting frequencies of each array element
We have:
1 occurring 0 times.
2 occurring 2 times.
3 occurring 2 times.
4 occurring 0 times.
5 occurring 1 time.

problem link :
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/frequency-of-array-elements-1587115620/1

```
class Solution:
    #Function to count the frequency of all elements from 1 to N in the array.
    def frequencycount(self,A,N):
        s = {}
        for i in A:
            if i in s:
                s[i] += 1
            else:
                s[i] = 1
        for i in range(1,len(A)+1):
            if i in s:
                A[i-1] = s[i]
            else:
                A[i-1]=0


        return A

#{ 
#  Driver Code Starts
#Initial Template for Python 3

import math
if __name__=="__main__":
    T=int(input())
    while(T>0):
        N=int(input())
        A=[int(x) for x in input().strip().split()]
        ob=Solution()
        ob.frequencycount(A,N)
        for i in range (len (A)):
            print(A[i], end=" ")
        print()
        T-=1



# } Driver Code Ends
```

Comment: "But my code is not passing all the testcases. Can anyone please help me out here. " The first thing you should do is figure out which test cases don't pass, what happens when those test cases are run, and how that is different from what is supposed to happen. The second thing you should do is edit your post to show that information.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list

```
l = [0,2,5,6,0,5,3]
```

Then you can do:

```
res = [l.count(e) for e in range(max(l))]
```

This will give an array with the number of times a letter e is present in the original list.

Comment: I have used your approach but getting an TLe error. Can you please have a look at my code and suggest me where i am wrong?